# How to use a foreach loop with AJAX call?

Tags: php, arrays, ajax

I have a foreach loop that is called from my AJAX code. It appears that the foreach loop is being skipped right over. I would ultimately like to make it so that the foreach loop will execute a query using each value in the array, but I am first trying to test the the foreach loop works (which it does not). The alert (from my AJAX) that I am receiving is just the original array and not the one with the added items.

PHP:

```
   $data = array();
   if(isset($_POST['myArray']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']){ 
    $data = $_POST['myArray']; 
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        $data[] = $item;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
    die();      
}
```

AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn-addkegs').click(function() {
        var arr = kegs;
        var myArray =  JSON.stringify(arr);

        $.ajax({
            url: "addkegs.php",
            method: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {myArray: myArray},
            success: function (result) {
            alert("Your kegs have been added! These include: " + result);
            textarea.value = "";
            kegs = [];
         }
                    });

            });
        });
```

As for the line `var arr = kegs;`, the value of the array 'kegs' is set through an input field and other AJAX, but all that works fine. I think that my problem is with my PHP code.

Comment: Your loop appears to be trying to modify the same variable over which it iterates.  What is the actual value of `$data` at runtime?

Comment: @David Based off the user input I tested, the value of $data = ["1","2","3"] and the alert I am receiving returns the same value ["1","2","3"] .

Comment: If you're seeing the value in the alert after the AJAX response, what's the actual problem?

Comment: In the PHP code, is `$data` an *array*, or a *string* which *looks like* an array?  What is the raw result from the AJAX response, not what's in the alert?

Comment: @David How can I check the raw result? (I am inexperienced)

Comment: In your browser's debugging tools, take a look at the network requests.  Examine the AJAX request and its response.  If the result is entirely wrapped in quotes, then it's just a string and not an array.  You may need to JSON-*decode* `$_POST['myArray']` server-side to interpret it as an array.

Comment: @jh95 can you try to put a debug command or breakpoint inside the foreach to see for sure if it has been executed? If the output was not changed, it is likely that the code inside foreach has not executed.

Comment: @Klaus Is there some universal foreach debug code that will let me know if it is running?

Comment: @jh95 you can place an echo, for example: echo "Inside loop"; inside the foreach, then open the browser console (firebug or chrome console) to see if the string "Inside loop" appear (you can do that as David shown above).

Comment: @Klaus I placed echo "Inside loop"; on the line after $data[] = $item; and in Chrome's debugging console, nothing appeared.

Comment: @jh95 you did it correctly. Nothing appear means the code block inside foreach has not executed which means the code block inside the if statement may not not executed. You should check your conditions in the if statement.

Comment: @Klaus  Since echo json_encode($data); is in the if statement and it is running (since I am getting the AJAX alert with the array), wouldn't that mean that the if statement is working properly?

Comment: @Klaus Does my AJAX code appear to be passing the JS array to PHP as a string as suggested by @David?

Comment: @jh95 sorry, my bad. I missed the closing curly bracket of the if. So now we are sure that the if statement has executed. You should debug data before and after foreach to see if it has changed. Just place var_dump($data); before and after foreach to see if the data has changed as expected.

Comment: @jh95 it looks like a string which looks like an array. like David mentioned.

Comment: @Klaus When I added var_dump($data); in the spots you mentioned, I no longer got my AJAX alert and the console was still empty.

Comment: it should output something event if the data is empty.

Comment: @Klaus where will it output? The console was empty

Comment: in the console. You should see it as it is here http://prntscr.com/ddgxcy

Comment: @Klaus when I add var_dump($data); before and after foreach, my console is still empty and no AJAX alert

Comment: @David You were right with your JSON-decode `$_POST['myArray']` comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are send via post only values... like in comments : 1,2,3
your $_POST['myArray'] was receive literaly what you sent to.

So, data variable will receive the array that seems like this ['1','2','3']

Well... Since you are not creating a variable $data as an Array, and yes, only putting an array inside it.

The PHP doesnt consider the $data[] variable as same as $data.

So, the PHP was magicaly overwriting the values from each same values.

So, I think if you want to repeat the values in the same array, you must reference the array with the array_push

```
$data = $_POST['myArray']; 
foreach ($data as $item) {
    array_push($data, $item);
}
```

Now when you return this array, you will have a response like {1,2,3,1,2,3}

Comment: Remember in your function you are not putting new values, you only was getting the values from a post and putting this values into a "new array" with the same name.

Comment: Using that code, I got the same result, and alert displaying ["1","2","3"]

Comment: Wow your code have an error:
Your empty function are not closed... Or you copy this code wrong, or your if is not passing...

if(isset($_POST['myArray']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']){

Please, check if your code are right. And test your if without the function empty server...

Comment: My if statement is working because I am getting an alert from AJAX from the echo json_encode($data);

Comment: Copy the if statement from your ide here again pls

Comment: if(isset($_POST['myArray']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])){ 
  $data = $_POST['myArray']; 
  foreach ($data as $item) {
   array_push($data, $item);
  }
  echo json_encode($data);

    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129391/discussion-between-ramon-schmidt-rocha-and-jh95).

Answer (score 0):

Answer from a comment by @David:

> In your browser's debugging tools, take a look at the network requests. Examine the AJAX request and its response. If the result is entirely wrapped in quotes, then it's just a string and not an array. You may need to JSON-decode $_POST['myArray'] server-side to interpret it as an array.

I needed to change `$data = $_POST['myArr'];` to `$data = json_decode($_POST['myArr']);`.